# Joining parent and child records in solr Hybris using _root_

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

In Solr,we have documents with a `_root_` field.
The parent and child records are interconnected with `_root_`. The `_root_` parameter will be the same for the parent and their corresponding children.
The `type_string` fields of parents and children are different. We need to do a join on parent and child using root.

How do I do a join between orders and `schedulelines` and fetch `orders` based on a filter applied to `ScheduleLineDetail` for "date"?

```json
      {
            "id":"7503",
            "type_string":"Order",      
            "_version_":1763406080353763328,
            "_root_":"7503"
     }
     {
            "id":"7503_20",
            "entryNumber_string":"20",       
            "type_string":"OrderEntry",
            "_root_":"7503"
    }
    {
            "id":"7503_20_null",
            "date":"2023-04-20T22:39:18Z",
             "type_string":"ScheduleLineDetail",
            "_root_":"7503"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible via writing `CustomSolrQueryConvertor` and override `convertSolrQuery` method.
Example:

```java
public class CustomSolrQueryConvertor extends DefaultSolrQueryConverter implements SolrQueryConverter, BeanFactoryAware {
    
    @override
    public SolrQuery convertSolrQuery(SearchQuery searchQuery) throws FacetSearchException {
    SolrQuery solrQuery = super.convertSolrQuery(searchQuery);
    String dateQuery = "date:"+new Date();
    solrQuery.add("fq", "q={!join from=root to=root}type_string:OrderEntry AND"+dateQuery);
    }
    return solrQuery;
    }
```

**Note: This is an example, you need to adjust DATE parameter according to your document or requirement.**